# Powershell Azure : The term 'Get-AutomationConnection' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to connect to an Azure Run As connection, as part of a Powershell script that does a backup of a database.

This script attempts to call  `Get-AutomationConnection`

As seen in the screenshot, `Get-Module` does return that `Azure` / `Azure.Storage` and `AzureRM` shows.

What module should I import in addition for this to work?

[image]

Comment: pretty sure `get-automationconnection` is used in runbooks only to retrieve data frmo Azure Automation internally, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I see you're logging in to ARM. Did you try Get-AzureRMAutomationConnection?

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Backup-Azure-SQL-Databases-bbeea33e - I thought I could get a powershell to work locally, then upload it to azure and fire it as a function. Attempting to run the powershell from the link to Backup Azure SQL Databases to Blob storage

Comment: @PeterPitLock The script runs on Azure Runbook, you should run `New-AzureRmAutomationConnection` on your local.

Comment: Thanks Walter, do you know whether it would be possible to do this (Azure Function  in Powershell to backup SQL Azure to SQL Blob)? My knowledge on the logging in is the issue now. I'm thinking of rather going this route :https://cmatskas.com/copy-azure-blob-data-between-storage-accounts-using-functions/

Comment: @PeterPitLock Sorry, I'm not good at this. If possible, you could ask a new question about this. You could refer to this link:[Back up Multiple Databases to Azure Blob Storage - PowerShell
](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/back-up-multiple-databases-to-azure-blob-storage-powershell). If my answer is helpful, don't forget to accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to connect to an Azure Run As connection from Windows PowerShell, you should use [`New-AzureRmAutomationConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.automation/new-azurermautomationconnection?view=azurermps-3.8.0).

```
$ConnectionAssetName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
$ConnectionFieldValues = @{"ApplicationId" = $Application.ApplicationId; "TenantId" = $TenantID.TenantId; "CertificateThumbprint" = $Cert.Thumbprint; "SubscriptionId" = $SubscriptionId}
New-AzureRmAutomationConnection -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -AutomationAccountName $AutomationAccountName -Name $ConnectionAssetName -ConnectionTypeName AzureServicePrincipal -ConnectionFieldValues $ConnectionFieldValues
```

You are able to use the script to create the connection asset because when you create your Automation account, it automatically includes several global modules by default along with the connection type AzurServicePrincipal to create the AzureRunAsConnection connection asset.

`Get-AutomationConnection` runs in Azure runbook internally.

Please refer to [connection assets in Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-connections).

Answer (score 0):

If you want similar functionality to runbooks on-premise, you can install [AzureAutomationAuthoringToolkit](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAutomationAuthoringToolkit/0.2.3.8). It will give you very similar functionality. I have one script that logs in using the service principal, whether it is running on-premise or in an Azure runbook. It uses the resources provided by AAATK when running on-premise, that simulate a runbook.

I did try using the version of Get-AutomationConnection that comes with the "Microsoft Monitoring agent" (Hybrid worker), but I have since read that it is different to the one that comes with AzureAutomationAuthoringToolkit, detailed in the "Known Issues" in the [GitHub readme](https://github.com/azureautomation/azure-automation-ise-addon/blob/master/README.md). I couldn't get it to work, so I reverted to AAATK's version.

Comment: `AzureAutomationAuthoringToolkit` does not support Powershell 7!

Comment: This answer is over 4 years old! Things have progressed somewhat. AAATK was an "extension" for PowerShell ISE. ISE doesn't work with PS 6.x or 7.x. AAATK is no longer maintained as there are a bunch of other tools that have replaced it.